# Is there a full canon version of Tyrion's jackass/honeycomb joke?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Throughout *Game of Thrones* Tyrion attempts to tell a joke about walking into a brothel with honeycomb and a jackass but never gets to finish it. I know of a similar joke but wondered if there is a canonical answer/punchline to his joke?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

As far as I know Tyrion only tries to tell the joke thrice and each time is interrupted almost as soon as he begins. In season 1 episode 6, "A Golden Crown", at his trial he barely gets the opening line out of the way:

> **Tyrion:** I once brought a jackass and a honeycomb into a brothel...

Much later on in season 6 episode 8, "No One", he doesn't get much further:

> **Tyrion:** I once walked into a brothel with a honeycomb and a jackass. The madam says...

Lastly, in season 8 episode 6, "The Iron Throne", the scene ends with him starting it.

> **Tyrion:** I once brought a jackass and a honeycomb into a brothel.

So, the answer to is there a canonical answer is no. If you want some possibilities of what it could be, I know of a few; here are a couple from [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones/comments/6l85om/everythingtyrions_honeycomb_and_jackass_joke/).

> Tyrion walks into a brothel with a honeycomb and a jackass.
>
> Madame: What can we do for you?
>
> Tyrion: I need a woman to lay with, for mine has left me.
>
> Madame: Whatever for? And what's with the honeycomb and the mule?
>
> Tyrion: My woman found a genie in a bottle, and he granted her three wishes. The first was for a house fit for a queen, so he gave her this damn honeycomb. The second wish was that she have the nicest ass in all the land, so he gave her this damn donkey...
>
> Madame: And what about the third wish?
>
> Tyrion: Well... she asked the genie to make my cock hang down past my knee.
>
> Madame: Well that one's not so bad eh?
>
> Tyrion: Not so bad!? I used to be six foot three!

> I once took a honeycomb and a jackass into a brothel, and the madam asked me what I wanted. I said I would like to trade the honeycomb for a meal, and the jackass for a night with the most beautiful woman.
>
> She asked me why I did not simply eat the honeycomb. I said the same reason I want to trade the jackass, I'm tired of having the same thing every night.

Comment: Heard the 'used to be 6'3"' one before. Any idea if the joke will be completed this coming season or is Tyrion to somber now to joke anymore?

Comment: We will have to wait and see.

Comment: @Seamusthedog you mean somber or sober?

Comment: @Blueriver somber, don't think he's on the wagon.

Comment: It seems as though this joke is a Noodle Incident.

Comment: @chrylis that's a new term to my but exactly what I think, nice one!

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoodleIncident

Comment: @Holger Oh wow I didn't realize it had a name. It reminds me of the time the (Christopher Nolan) Joker explained how he got that scar, but he kept telling people different stories - further showing how much of a sociopath he is. That was (one of) the best part(s) of his character.

Comment: @Seamusthedog looks like you got your answer to both. No; not completed but referenced again.